# How to push data to Firebase realtime database from .NET Core 6

Tags: firebase, asp.net-core-6.0

I want to store document to Firebase realtime DB and than push part of it to end user by my Net core application. Currently I have configured DB and this line in my program working fine. I can see in the debugger auth object, project URL and that's it.

```
 Dim FB As FirebaseApp = FirebaseApp.Create(New AppOptions() With 
      {
        .Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("xxxxx.json")
      })
```

But what next? I expect something like FB.Firestore.Push() or something similar method to store Json object to Firebase, but can not see it.

[image: Auth succesfull]

Currently I have installed package FirebaseAdmin and no more, need to add something package? Or something need to allow in Firebase console?